# R: Large xml with string data in tags. Working with xmlEventParse + xpathSApply

Tags: r, xml, large-data, xpathsapply

I have lots of very large (>10GB) xml files in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<records xmlns="http://website”>
<REC rid=“this is a test”>
    <UID>ABCD123</UID>
    <data_1>
        <fullrecord_metadata>
            <references count=“2”>
                <reference>
                    <uid>ABCD2345</uid>
                </reference>
                <reference>
                    <uid>ABCD3456</uid>
                </reference>
            </references>
        </fullrecord_metadata>
    </data_1>
</REC>
<REC rid=“this is a test”>
    <UID>XYZ0987</UID>
    <data_1>
        <fullrecord_metadata>
            <references count=“N”>
            </references>
        </fullrecord_metadata>
    </data_1>
</REC>
</records>
```

The goal is to create a dataset as follows:

```
str_UID    str_ref      str_tot
ABCD123    ABCD2345     2
ABCD123    ABCD3456     2
XYZ0987    NULL         N
```

where all variables are strings.

The tricky part is extracting the "2" and "N", preserving them as strings.

From a previous post ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187461/r-xmleventparse-with-large-varying-node-xml-input-and-conversion-to-data-frame/46193998#46193998)) I was able to generate the first two rows using the following code, which relies on xmlEventParse to read the elements directly via xpathSApply without loading in the xml file to memory (which is not feasible for the full data):

```
 uid_traverse <- function() {
 uids <- ""
 refs <- "" 

 REC <- function(x) {
  uid <- xpathSApply(x, "//UID", xmlValue)
  ref <- xpathSApply(x, "//reference/uid", xmlValue)

  if (length(uid) > 0) {
   if (length(var) == 0) {
    uids <<- c(uids, uid)
    refs <<- c(refs, NA_character_)
   } else {
   uids <<- c(uids, rep(uid, length(ref)))
   refs <<- c(refs, ref)
   } 
  } 
 }

 list(
  REC = REC, 
  uid_df = function() { 
  data.frame(uid = uids, ref = refs, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
 )
}
 uid_f <- uid_traverse()
 invisible(
 xmlEventParse(
 file = path.expand(url), 
 branches = uid_f["REC"])
)
DF <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, uid_f$uid_df())
```

However, since the data I'm interested in - here the "2" and the "N" - is contained within the tag brackets <>, I can't figure out how to modify xpathSApply or xmlEventParse to extract these strings.

Note: the real data setting is that these values are not simply the counts of the information contained within the sub-elements, but are identification codes so I must extract them directly instead of inferring from the number of sub-elements, etc.

Comment: Figured out I need to utilize the "xmlAttrs" option of xpathSApply to get the info out of the tag, but can't get the function to keep the number of rows even.